# Changing active tab using angular

Tags: html, angularjs, servicenow

Angular tab change on new value?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a class="A" data-target="#A">Nye({{c.data.feil_nye_ant}})</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav">
        <a class="B" data-target="#B">Aktive({{c.data.feil_aktive_ant}})</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav">
        <a class="C" data-target="#C">HASTER({{c.data.feil_haster_ant}})</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav">
        <a class="D" data-target="#D">Ferdige({{c.data.feil_ferdig_ant}})</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Need to draw focus by opening the "HASTER" tab (means "urgent"), when the value of `c.data.feil_haster_ant` is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` to make your tabs active. When you perform an event on the tab (like click), set the value of some condition to trigger changes for the css of that tab using `ng-class`.

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"  ng-class="{'active': Some condition}">
        <a class="A" data-target="#A">Nye({{c.data.feil_nye_ant}})</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav"  ng-class="{'active': Some condition}">
        <a class="B" data-target="#B">Aktive({{c.data.feil_aktive_ant}})</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav"  ng-class="{'active': Some condition}">
        <a class="C" data-target="#C">HASTER({{c.data.feil_haster_ant}})</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav"  ng-class="{'active': Some condition}">
        <a class="D" data-target="#D">Ferdige({{c.data.feil_ferdig_ant}})</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
.active{
 your css styles for active tab 
}
```

Comment: The tab should be switched by the code (not the user), in this case.

Comment: Then switch the value in the controller while the trigger happens

Comment: Hello Vivz , what can be condition?